# Cursor 'can't get out' from iframe to parent, using Tab key (only Firefox)

Tags: html, css

I've got a form in which there are couple of iframes. 
There is only one form with one input inside each of those iframes. 
When page is loaded I try to switch between inputs using Tab button.

On Chrome everything goes well - after pushing Tab, cursor skips to another input which is inside iframe.

On Firefox cursor 'enters' the first iframe and focus on input, but then if I try to switch field using tab, nothing happens, it's just can get out of the iframe to it's parent form :/

Is there some way to fix focusing on FF, to work just like on Chrome ?

I've tried to set tabindex on each field, but nothing has changed.

```html
<form>
   <iframe id='first-iframe'>
      <form>
       <input type="text" id="first-input"/>
      <form>
   </iframe>
   <iframe id='second-iframe'>
      <form>
        <input type="text" id="second-input"/>
      <form>
    </iframe>
    <iframe id='third-iframe'>
       <form>
         <input type="text" id="third-input"/>
       <form>
    </iframe>
</form>
```